# Kaitai struct - change default endianness based on a condition in the file

Tags: kaitai-struct

I'm dealing with files from two versions of a video game - one for the PC, one for the PS3. It's possible to tell which version of the game that a certain file comes from if the first four 4 bytes of the header - if `struct.unpack_from("<f", data)` says one number, it's from the PC, but if it doesn't, then `struct.unpack_from(">f", data)` should give that number. From there, the rest of the data is read accordingly.

I'm trying to write a parser for these files using Kaitai struct, but it seems like my options are to generate two separate KSY files for the LE and BE versions of the files, or two separate types, something like

```
seq:
  - id: sample_rate
    type: u4le
  - id: header
    type: header_le
    if: sample_rate == 1234
  - id: header
    type: header_be
    if: sample_rate == 4321


types:
  header_le:
    - id: sample_count
      type: u4le
    - id: channel_count
      type: u4le
  header_be:
    - id: sample_count
      type: u4be
    ...
```

Either option works in the end, but I was hoping for something a bit less repetitive. Does Kaitai struct support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affiliate disclaimer: I'm a [Kaitai Struct](https://kaitai.io/) maintainer (see my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/generalmimon)).

> Does Kaitai struct support this?

Yes, see https://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#calc-endian. In the top-level `seq`, you typically directly include only the field indicating the endianness, and the rest of the format (affected by the selected endianness) needs to be moved to a subtype where you will use `meta/endian/{switch-on,cases}`.

```yaml
seq:
  - id: sample_rate
    type: u4le
  - id: header
    type: header_type

types:
  header_type:
    meta:
      endian:
        switch-on: _root.sample_rate
        cases:
          '0x0102_0304': le
          '0x0403_0201': be
    seq:
      - id: sample_count
        type: u4 # this will be parsed as 'le' or 'be' as decided in `meta/endian`
      - id: channel_count
        type: u4
```

Note that any user-defined types in which you want to inherit the endianness decided in `/types/header_type/meta/endian` must be defined somewhere under `/types/header_type/types/...`. It's suggested in the [User Guide](https://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#calc-endian) example (note the `ifd` type):

```yaml
types:
  tiff_body:
    meta:
      endian:
        switch-on: _root.indicator
        cases:
          '[0x49, 0x49]': le
          '[0x4d, 0x4d]': be
    seq:
      - id: version
        type: u2
      # ...
    types:
      ifd:
        # inherits endianness of `tiff_body`
```

If you define them at the top level (same as `header_type`), they would not inherit the endianness from `header_type` and you'll probably get something similar to `error: unable to use type 'u4' without default endianness`.

For more examples, check out the .ksy specs in the format gallery that use it - [image/exif.ksy](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/1a9e8db8a512dfc8daa4d5b85a0a9bce81a45e15/image/exif.ksy#L14-L26), [executable/elf.ksy](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/1a9e8db8a512dfc8daa4d5b85a0a9bce81a45e15/executable/elf.ksy#L258-L264) or [database/gettext_mo.ksy](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/1a9e8db8a512dfc8daa4d5b85a0a9bce81a45e15/database/gettext_mo.ksy#L118-L123).

Comment: thanks! follow up question: is it possible to use an if-else instead of switch-on? like, if the indicator was greater than a certain value then it's LE, otherwise it's BE

Comment: @vardonir Yes, it's possible. You have to use switch-on to switch the endianness, but note that it can contain an arbitrary expression, so you can write `switch-on: _root.indicator > 100` and then use `true: le` and `_: be` in cases (`_` means an "else case", as mentioned in https://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#calc-endian).